# selecting common columns from different elements of a list

Tags: r

I have a data set in list format. The list is further divide into 20 elements. Each element contains 12 rows and some columns. Now I want to extract common columns from each element of the list and make a new data set. I try to make a reproducible example. Please see code

```
a<-data.frame(x=(1:10),y=(1:10),z=(1:10))
b<-data.frame(x=(1:10),y=(1:10),n=(1:10))
c<-data.frame(x=(1:10),y=(1:10),q=(1:10))
data<-list(a,b,c)
data1<-ldply(data)
required_data<-data1[,-3:-5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the common columns using `Reduce`, subset them from list and bind them together

```
cols <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(data, colnames))
do.call(rbind, lapply(data, `[`, cols))

#    x  y
#1   1  1
#2   2  2
#3   3  3
#4   4  4
#5   5  5
#6   6  6
#7   7  7
#8   8  8
#9   9  9
#10 10 10
#11  1  1
#...
```

The last step can also be performed using

```
purrr::map_df(data, `[`, cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

with `base R`, you can fist find the names in common

```
commonName <- names((r<-table(unlist(Map(names,data))))[r>1])
```

then retrieve the columns from list and integrate (similar to the second step in the solution by [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59100547/12158757))

```
res <- Reduce(rbind,lapply(data, '[',commonName))
```

which gives:

```
> res
    x  y
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  6
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
10 10 10
11  1  1
12  2  2
13  3  3
14  4  4
15  5  5
16  6  6
17  7  7
18  8  8
19  9  9
20 10 10
21  1  1
22  2  2
23  3  3
24  4  4
25  5  5
26  6  6
27  7  7
28  8  8
29  9  9
30 10 10
```